# Apple Mach-O Linker Error - duplicate symbols

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, linker

I'm having a little trouble with an app I'm making. I researched this a bit and looked at other posts, but the fixes that they proposed don't work for me. I am running all the latest softwares.

It says:

3 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
Linker command failed with exit code 1 ( use -v to see invocation)

> Ld
>   /Users/RileyLloyd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/People_Bingo-eqtneohyjbwwpxclkkhkbtkcddye/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/People\
>   Bingo.app/People\ Bingo normal i386
>       cd "/Users/RileyLloyd/Documents/Xcode/People Bingo"
>       setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 7.0
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk
>   -L/Users/RileyLloyd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/People_Bingo-eqtneohyjbwwpxclkkhkbtkcddye/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/RileyLloyd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/People_Bingo-eqtneohyjbwwpxclkkhkbtkcddye/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -filelist /Users/RileyLloyd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/People_Bingo-eqtneohyjbwwpxclkkhkbtkcddye/Build/Intermediates/People\
>   Bingo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/People\
>   Bingo.build/Objects-normal/i386/People\ Bingo.LinkFileList -Xlinker
>   -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework
>   Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker
>   /Users/RileyLloyd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/People_Bingo-eqtneohyjbwwpxclkkhkbtkcddye/Build/Intermediates/People\
>   Bingo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/People\
>   Bingo.build/Objects-normal/i386/People\ Bingo_dependency_info.dat -o
>   /Users/RileyLloyd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/People_Bingo-eqtneohyjbwwpxclkkhkbtkcddye/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/People\
>   Bingo.app/People\ Bingo
>
> duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CollectionViewController._cellArray in:
>       /Users/RileyLloyd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/People_Bingo-eqtneohyjbwwpxclkkhkbtkcddye/Build/Intermediates/People
>   Bingo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/People
>   Bingo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
>       /Users/RileyLloyd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/People_Bingo-eqtneohyjbwwpxclkkhkbtkcddye/Build/Intermediates/People
>   Bingo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/People
>   Bingo.build/Objects-normal/i386/CollectionViewController.o duplicate
>   symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_CollectionViewController in:
>       /Users/RileyLloyd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/People_Bingo-eqtneohyjbwwpxclkkhkbtkcddye/Build/Intermediates/People
>   Bingo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/People
>   Bingo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
>       /Users/RileyLloyd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/People_Bingo-eqtneohyjbwwpxclkkhkbtkcddye/Build/Intermediates/People
>   Bingo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/People
>   Bingo.build/Objects-normal/i386/CollectionViewController.o duplicate
>   symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CollectionViewController in:
>       /Users/RileyLloyd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/People_Bingo-eqtneohyjbwwpxclkkhkbtkcddye/Build/Intermediates/People
>   Bingo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/People
>   Bingo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
>       /Users/RileyLloyd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/People_Bingo-eqtneohyjbwwpxclkkhkbtkcddye/Build/Intermediates/People
>   Bingo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/People
>   Bingo.build/Objects-normal/i386/CollectionViewController.o ld: 3
>   duplicate symbols for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two modules in your application (`ViewController` and `CollectionViewController`) have provided an implementation of class `CollectionViewController`.  The three duplication symbols are class metadata.

There are a number of ways you might have done this:

- You have two modules declaring the same class. Perhaps one is vestigial?
- The `@implementation CollectionViewController` appears in a `.h` file that is included in both `CollectionViewController.m` and `ViewController.m` - or you included a `.m` file somewhere.

Comment: It has been a long time since I have worked on this project because I couldn't solve that problem. I can't quite remember exactly how I wanted to code it, but the idea was to have a collection view controller as a page under the view controller (as shown in image in original question). What should I do to fix this? What files do you need me to post?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the issue. I was importing the "CollectionViewController.m" in to the "ViewController.m" file. I commented it out and it runs smoothly now.